# Android video rotate on samsung when play from web server

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I'm playing video from server in android using videoview, but in some samsung phone video is roatate.

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vidFull);
        vidFull.setMediaController(mediaController);
        vidFull.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        vidFull.requestFocus();
        vidFull.start();
```

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=249871&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: see above link .make sure you add `android:screenOrientation=` ?

Comment: screenOrientation is potrait